# Reference to method is ambiguous, with generics, odd behaviour

Tags: java, generics, overloading

Consider the following scenario:

```
class C {
  void m(Class<?> c1, Class<?> c2) {}
  <S, U extends S> void m(S s, U u) {}
}

class x {{
  final Class<Integer> cInteger = Integer.class;
  final Class<?> cSomething = null;
  final C c = new C();
  c.m(cInteger,  cInteger);
  c.m(cSomething,  cSomething); // *
}}
```

Using Oracle's javac, version 1.7.0_01 (and also 1.7.0, as well as OpenJDK's Java 7 and Java 6 compilers), I get an error on the line marked with `// *`:

> error: reference to m is ambiguous, both method m(Class,Class) in C and method m(S,U) in C match

I cannot understand why this happens: the compiler is able to tell which method is being called when the static type of the parameter is `Class<Integer>`, but it has problems with `Class<?>`.

IntelliJ's code analysis says this is OK, as well as JRockit's (or is it Sun's Java 6) compiler.

So, there is obviously a bug here, either in those softwares that say it is right, or in those that say it is wrong.

Note that if I remove the bound of `U` (that is, if I declare `m` as `<S, U> void M(S s, U u) {}`, it will compile without errors. Also, a call with a raw type (ie, `Class x = null; m(x, x)`) compiles fine as well.

So, according to the Java specification, is this code valid or invalid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure? My test is that the 1st `m(cInteger,  cInteger)` fails, and the 2nd `m(cSomething,  cSomething)` is ok. Also the raw `m(x,x)` doesn't compile.

(1) `m(cInteger,cInteger)` fails

Both m() match the arguments; for *m2*, inference yields `S=U=Class<Integer>`.

Now the question is, is *m1* more specific than *m2*? Following the procedure in 15.12.2.5, it is. If that is the case, there is no ambiguity; *m1* should be picked as the most specific method, and the call should compile.

However, this violates the *informal* requirement given by the spec: if *m1* is more specific than *m2*, any invocation handled by *m1* could be passed on to *m2* without a compile-time type error. For example, *m1* can accept arguments `(Class<Integer>,Class<String>)`, which *m2* can't (due to the less-than-perfect type inferrence
procedure).

Javac obviously adhere to the informal notion; this is probably because the formal spec has a bug - it should have included *capture conversion* (explained later) in the definition of *more specific* relation; then *m1* is not more specific than *m2*, therefore the call `m(cInteger,cInteger)` is ambiguous.

If another compiler strictly adheres to the formal spec, it's not its fault to inherit the spec's bug.

(2) `m(x, x)` fails

for the same reason as (1); both methods match, but neither is more specific than the other.

*m1* matches through *method invocation conversion*, which allows *unchecked conversion* from raw `Class` to `Class<?>`. *m2* matches after inferring `S=U=Class`

(3) `m(cSomething,  cSomething)` compiles

This is because *m1* is the only applicable one, there is therefore no ambiguity.

*m2* is not applicable, let's see why.

First, the types of the arguments are not exactly `(Class<?>,Class<?>)` - *capture conversion* is applied on them first. (Again, the spec is very unclear (see chapter 15), but I'm very certain that this is well understood to be the case; the type of any expression is applied with capture conversion)

So the arguments types are `(Class<X1>,Class<X2>)`, with two fresh type variables. There's another screwup here, a more precise conversion would've been `(Class<X1>,Class<X1>)`, unfortunately, capture conversion is applied twice, indepedently, yeilding two different types.

*m1* easily matches the argument types. But *m2* doesn't match, due to the less-than-perfect type inference procedure. The procedure first yields that `S=Class<X1>, U=Class<X2>`, *after which*, bounds of type variables are checked, where `U extends S` fails.

(4) removing U's bound

Now (1),(2),(3) all compile. Because without `U extends S`, inference passes.

For (1) and (2), *m1* is now more specific than *m2*, no longer ambiguity.

For (3), *m2* now matches; but then is shadowed by the more specific *m1*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because if you say in method call let `<S>` be of type `Class<?>` then `<U>` is also `Class<?>` and It's impossible to determine which method should be used.

```
<S, U extends S> void m(S s, U u) {} //S=U=Class<?> => void m(Class<?> s, Class<?> u) {} //same signature
```

If you say let `<S>` and `<U>` be type of `Class<Integer>` then it must be the second method with generics `<S>` and `<U>`.

```
<S, U extend S> void m(S s, U u) {} //S=U=Class<Integer> => void m(Class<Integer> s, Class<Integer> u) {} //Ok
```

Problem

`<S,U>` declaration specifies that your intend is to use two different unrelated types.